# Photoshop move layer along y-axis

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm working on a script that will move a layer, right, left, up, or down. This depends upon which edge of the layer is inside the canvas.

I've managed to get the layer moving left and right (x-axis) using bounds[0] and bounds[2].

But when I try to get it to move up or down, it still moves left/right. Is it the bounds number I've got wrong?

```
var Y1 = bounds[3].as('px');
var Height = app.activeDocument.height.as('px');

//move down
if (Y1 < Height) {
activeDocument.activeLayer.translate(Height-Y1); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you probably want to do in a situation like this is to check [the documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf). For `.translate()` we can find the following:

[image]

so to move horizontally we would use `deltaX` and to move vertically `deltaY`, in your code you're giving to `.translate()` only `deltaX`, so as expected your layer is being moved horizontally. To fix this pass `0` as a first argument and your `Height-Y1` as a second one:

```
activeDocument.activeLayer.translate(0, Height - Y1);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately, I still can't get it to move. At least it's not moving left or right now. Just stays still.

Comment: I tested your code before posting my answer and it was working corrrectly: if the layer is in the middle of the document it'll be translated to the bottom of the document. If it's not working for you there's probably something else what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, Sergey, apologies for taking so long to come back. I tested everything again this evening and it was working. Something’s changed since the other day; don’t know what. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great to hear that! Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you so the question would be closed