# How To space out photoshop Layers in a group horizontally with scripting v2019

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am new to scripting in photoshop and need to create a script to help with speeding up my workflow i cant find any pre done scripts to help me with this so im trying to do it my self (with all you to help please ),

basically what I am trying to do is have a group of layers have the layers inside it spread out evenly into positions according to the size of the image/layer and the art-board on a horizontal line for example:
if 1 image it is centred horizontally 
if 2 images they are place side by side
if 3 images they are the same as the 2 images but the 3rd one is in the center of the art-board
and so on 
but normally only working with up to 6 images a line on a 5000 x 5000 art-board

The other thing that im asking is if i need to select the group or if it could happen automatically sort of 
creating a template of sorts but thats not the main question  :)

Im not asking for a free script im just asking for help with what i should talk to to spread out layers on an art-board evenly.

Please Help Me with this.

Comment: So what help do you need exactly? If you're asking for someone to write a script for you, it's not help but a paid job.

Comment: no no im suck on the syntax sorry i dident make it more understandable you see almost all the scripts used that do similar things, look like this: runMenuItem(sTT('ungroupLayersEvent'));
and:
dsc.putReference(sTT('null'), ref1), dsc.putReference(sTT('from'), ref2);
 
but no reference to the variables or anything and there are strings used to define things that don't exist in my project but when i run the script it moves a group of layers to the center of the art-board so im really just asking what do i talk to to evenly spread out layers horizontally. 
sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you should update your question with the code you have and bits you're having issues with, otherwise it's not clear what's your question

Comment: i see you have done a post that explains things rather well,
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031370/photoshop-move-layer-along-y-axis/59031812#59031812)

i believe i didn't see it due to the wrong wording on my part when looking for the answer, i am sorry to of bothered you but your posts have already advised me in the right direction.

Comment: Found the answer on one of @Sergey's posts link is :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031370/photoshop-move-layer-along-y-axis/59031812#59031812

Comment: No worries. I'll mark your question as a duplicate then